# Google Drive REST API: cannot resolve method 'getFiles()'

Tags: android, rest, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an app that uses drive REST API to list and download files from Google drive. I am using resources from [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo).
But when adding below code to list all files, an error occurs saying that the method 'getFiles()' can't be resolved.

```
static void listFiles() {

    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(),
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(UT.acx, Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                    .setSelectedAccountName(UT.AM.getEmail())
    ).build();

    FileList result = null;
    try {
        result = service.files().list()
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No files found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Files:");
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did `result` object return a value?
If yes, try to insert your `list` object condition inside the try block.